# Unity Buttons Not Recieving Input

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've tried everything to figure out what's wrong.

Setting: I created a pause menu for a first person character controller that just makes a canvas appear with the pause menu.

Problem: The buttons on the canvas do not detect clicks, hovers, nothing.

My CharacterController has a PauseManager component (custom script) and the pause menu with the canvas as one of it's childs.

The PauseMananger class is as follows (relevant part):

```
public class PauseManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject pauseMenu;

    [SerializeField] KeyCode pauseKey = KeyCode.Escape; // I've tried with other keys
    bool isPaused = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        pauseMenu.SetActive(isPaused);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(pauseKey))
            PauseGame();

}

    void PauseGame()
    {
        isPaused = !isPaused;
        pauseMenu.SetActive(isPaused);

        if (isPaused)
        {
            Time.timeScale = 0;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
            Cursor.visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            Cursor.visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't think of a cause for this, I've created a main menu with a submenu (that appears when the user clicks on options) and it works perfectly. I've been debugging and searching google for hours, I have no idea why this is not working.

The problem might be due to the fact that it has a player controller? I don't kow, any ideas are apreciated.

Comment: Happened to me once, I found no reason for that behavior. But once I opened it after a while, the buttons worked. Try waiting for a while and test it out, if it doesn't work still, post a picture of your canvas inspector.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't some image be blocking raycasts for your menu? Maybe some transparent image or some object with CanvasGroup that has checked to block raycasts option.

I also faced the exact issue you are facing, when I had my UICanvas as prefab and I drag & dropped it into a new scene. No click, hover etc. events... I was going crazy until I found out that you need **EventSystem** inside of your scene in order to register a click, hover, etc. events. Usually, it is created automatically when you create a canvas, but when you copy the prefab as I did, it doesn't create a new EventSystem and you must create it manually.